# IntlDateFormatter. Timezone acronym lost when locale is changed

Tags: php, timezone, intldateformatter

im trying to do something like this (https://www.php.net/manual/en/intldateformatter.getlocale.php):

```
<?php
$fmt = new IntlDateFormatter(
    'en_US',
    IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
    IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
    'America/Los_Angeles',
    IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN
);
echo 'locale of the formatter is : ' . $fmt->getLocale();
echo 'First Formatted output is ' . $fmt->format(0);

$fmt = new IntlDateFormatter(
    'de-DE',
    IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
    IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
    'America/Los_Angeles',
    IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN
);
echo 'locale of the formatter is : ' . $fmt->getLocale();
echo 'Second Formatted output is ' . $fmt->format(0);

?>
```

the output is:

```
locale of the formatter is : en
First Formatted output is Wednesday, December 31, 1969 4:00:00 PM PT
locale of the formatter is : de
Second Formatted output is Mittwoch, 31. Dezember 1969 16:00 Uhr GMT-08:00
```

but i don't want the "GMT-08:00", i want to keep the **PT** acronym, is there any way to change the language in the date but keep the timezone acronym?

Thank you.

Comment: Timezone abbreviations are not globally unique, and are therefore tied to the locale in IntlDateFormatter. If you want to keep the American abbreviation you'll need to use the American formatter for at least the timezone portion of the string. However, 'PT' likely either won't have any particular meaning to German people, or might be taken to mean something other than "American Pacific Time".

Comment: @Sammitch makes sense, i will try to use the american formatter for the last part. Thank you.